# Converting .pbf to PostrgreSQL table using osm2pgsql?

Tags: python, postgresql, osm2pgsql

I try to import a .pbf file into a PostgreSQL table using osm2pgsql in python using the subprocess module.

The command works perfectly in the command-line, but when I try to use it in subprocess it errors out with:

> osm2pgsql version 0.92.0 (64 bit id space)
>
> Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR: Couldn't open style file
>   'C:/libs/share/osm2pgsql/default.style': No such file or directory

The Command Prompt is:

```
osm2pgsql -c -l -r pbf -p singapore-d osm -U postgres -H localhost -S D:/default.style D:/malaysia-singapore-brunei-latest.osm.pbf
```

The Python Code is:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['osm2pgsql', '-c', '-l', '-r', 'pbf', '-p', 'singapore', '-d', 'osm', '-U', 'postgres', '-H',
             'localhost', '-S', 'D:/default.style','D:/malaysia-singapore-brunei-latest.osm.pbf'],
            shell=True, env={'PATH': 'C:\osm2pgsql'})
```

Comment: would you please try using double quotes?